# How can I store references to Java objects in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

How can I store references to Java objects in Neo4j?

Comment: Only [OODB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database)s use to store object references, other databases don't do that. In Neo4j you would rather use a relationship to connect the entities. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j basically stores primitives like integers and strings. See the full reference on what can be stored in the apidocs for [setProperty](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to store objects into neo4j by first marshaling them to an XML (I'm using Xstream for that) and then unmarshaling when querying.